# Martini templates and tests

Tags: go, martini

I'm trying to split my application files from my testing files. It looks something like this:

```
main.go
views/
  layouts/
    layout.html
spec/
  main_test.go
```

`main.go` creates a Martini app and tells `Martini.render` where to look for the views:

```
func CreateApplication() {
  m := martini.Classic()
  m.Use(render.Renderer(render.Options{
    Directory: "views",
    Layout: "layouts/layout",
    Extensions: []string{".html"},
  }))
}
```

That all works really well when I'm using `go run` from the root folder. However, when I try to use the `CreateApplication()` function from the `spec/main_test.go` file, it's now looking for the views in `spec/views` because that's the run folder.

I went down the route of trying to use `runtime.Caller()` to get the absolute path, but that totally messes up when compilling the a binary.

I guess my question is how I can make this work? I want that `CreateApplication()` to work the same no matter where it was called from.

Comment: Use an absolute path instead of a relative one?

Comment: Edited to say "absolute" instead of "relative". If I can indeed get an absolute path and it works, I would love to see the code. I can't get  `os.Getwd()` and `filepath.Join` to work.

Comment: I ended up just passing in a string with the relative path to root. Follow progress here: https://github.com/runemadsen/golang-rails-template.

Comment: Would https://github.com/opennota/pathlib help getting that absolute path? (with their Cwd function: https://github.com/opennota/pathlib#func--cwd)

Answer (score 1):

I often run into this problem. What I do in such cases, is to create a symlink from the child directory to the folder in the root directory which holds the templates. Up until now I haven't had any problems using this appraoch, but when an app goes to production I delete those symlinks. I actually have a script that creates the symlinks before I start testing, and then deletes them after I'm done.

In your case, it would look like this (I'm on Ubuntu or Cygwin):

```
main.go
views/
  layouts/
    layout.html
spec/
  main_test.go

$ cd spec
$ ln -s ../views views

main.go
views/
  layouts/
    layout.html
spec/
  main_test.go
  views <- this is the symlink
```

Now, when running your tests from `spec/` the views directoy is found. I hope it helps you, and if my approach is somehow flawed, I'm eager to know!